# Adding GraphicsMagick to an Xcode project

Tags: c, xcode, frameworks, dylib, graphicsmagick

I have created a Foundation Tool in Xcode, and want to use some functions from the [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) image manipulation library. The library has been compiled and installed on my computer using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/). I added `libGraphicsMagick.3.dylib` and `libGraphicsMagickWand.2.dylib` to my project as external frameworks.

What other steps must I take to use these libraries in my application, and how would I import their headers to use their functions in my code?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: Made some progress. Used the `.a` static libraries instead of the dylibs, added them to my project, then added the header files for `magick` and `wand`. I'm trying to compile, but I get this error:
[alt text http://cl.ly/f4233cddbae23e1a19fc/content](http://cl.ly/f4233cddbae23e1a19fc/content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched around a bit, and apparently this problem occurs because 2 of the `typedef enum` declarations that GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick use are already defined in OS X framework headers. The enums in question are `ColorInfo` and `ExceptionInfo`.

The only way to fix it is to go through the source and rename every occurance of those enums to a new name that isn't already taken. However, the iPhone does not have this issue and GraphicsMagick will compile just fine. Unfortunately, I don't think the people behind the library are willing to rename their enums just to get it to compile on OS X.